# Mouse wheel doesn't scroll in windows 7 remote desktop

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, mouse, scrolling, mouse-wheel

I recently upgraded to windows 7. I realized that the mouse scroll wheel no longer works in the remote desktop. The remote machine has been the same, so I bet the problem is on the client side.

I am using microsoft (ironic) wireless mouse 5000 and microsoft wireless keyboard 3000.

Anybody had this problem before?

Comment: Are you using a [KVM switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kvm_switch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MS Wireless Mouse 5000 does some weird stuff with the scroll wheel.

If you haven't already, install the latest [IntelliPoint software](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/downloads) from Microsoft and see if that helps.

If you *have* already installed it, try removing it and just using the default "Windows Optical USB Mouse" driver that comes with windows.

Some related info:

- [Workaround for Microsoft Wireless Mouse 5000 Scroll Wheel Issue](http://techietalkz.com/2011/04/10/how-to-workaround-for-microsoft-wireless-mouse-5000-scroll-wheel-issue/)
- [Microsoft Mouse 5000 Scrolling wheel problem and windows 7](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/microsoft-mouse-5000-scrolling-wheel-problem-and/075a8659-7b3d-4a38-b08d-8451184cf2cb)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I fixed it by using the autohotkey script mentioned in your link. However, why do you think this is a microsoft mouse's problem? sounds like it is because other programs did not response to movement whose delta<120 ?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the wonderful windows program KatMouse (it allows you to scroll whichever window you are hovering over), disable it.

I'm using windows 8.1 and scroll did not work in remote desktop because I had KatMouse enabled.

Comment: Same here. Although KayMouse is a sweet program, it has caused a few of these strange issues.

Answer (score 1):

I was also finally able to get this working using AutoHotKey and this script

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; 
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 200 

; Installing the mousewheel handler only for the programs presenting this issue. 
; Remote Desktop
GroupAdd, MousewheelHandler, ahk_class TscShellContainerClass 

#IfWinActive ahk_group MousewheelHandler 
WheelDown::WheelDown 
WheelUp::WheelUp 
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```